# SQL Server BIDS data manipulation

Tags: sql-server, bids

I have an Excel Source and an OLE database destination. For the column mappings I need to first perform some data manipulations on the columns.

How do I get a substring from one of the source columns to be mapped to one of the destination columns?

How can I use a lookup table on one of my columns to get the value associated with the lookup table and then map that value to one of my destination columns?

I would like to use C# scripts as much as needed.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use Derived column transformation to get the substring of a source column .

Expression

```
 SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,START,END)
```

In the derived column tab select add as a new Row .Then map this new column in the destination .For the lookup transformation please see my reply to one of the SO questions
   [Lookup Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944968/create-a-ssis-package-to-copy-data-from-oracle-to-sql-server/10945532#10945532)

In order to do this in C# drag a script component onto the designer.Select the input and outputs and then add a new column ( Example NewColumn as the name)

```
   public class ScriptMain:UserComponent
  {


  public override CreateNewOutputRows()
  {
    int space = Row.SourceColumnName.IndexOf(' ');
  Row.NewColumn= Row.SourceColumnName.Substring(0,space)

  //If you need to retrieve the characters after second dot then
  //int firstDot=Row.Column.IndexOf('.')
  //int secondDot=Row.Column.IndexOf('.',firstDot+1)
 // Row.Newcolumn=Row.SourceColumnName.Substring(secondDot,Row.SorceColumnName.Length)
  }
  }
```

Comment: I need more generality for START and END. Such as the first whitespace character position, or the second dot position. I know this is easily acheivable in a programming language. So how do I do this in a C# script?